# rails active record group by for child class

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord, group-by

```
class Goal
  has_many :tasks
end

class Task
  belongs_to :goal
end
```

For each Goal, I would like to get all its tasks grouped by the task attribute size. Then in the view I can display a table which shows the number of tasks for each size.

```
Goal A
 size  count
  sm    5
  med   3
  lg    4
  xl    2

Goal B
 size  count
  sm    10
  med   7
  lg    8
  xl    0
```

Initially I just had a table with tasks and was able to achieve what I wanted with

```
Task.group(:size).count.sort_by { |size, _| size }
```

Now that I have added a parent class, Goal, is there a way with an active query record to get all tasks for each goal and have the tasks grouped by size?

Answer (score 0):

If Goal has many Tasks then you can do
`goal.tasks.group(:size).count.sort_by { |size, _| size }` where goal might be `goal = Goal.find_by(id: 1)`